Steam Remote Storage FileWrite Fails After Adding New Files to Steam Cloud
I am new to Steam game development and I'm encountering an issue with storing data in Steam Cloud using Steamworks. Previously, I was able to use SteamRemoteStorage.FileWrite to save data to Steam Cloud without any problems. However, recently, I’ve started experiencing failures when trying to add new files to Steam Cloud, while all previous functionality remains operational.
Here is the code that was working before:
public float hungry = 100;


public void SaveHungryToSteam() {
    if (SteamManager.Initialized) {
        CSteamID steamID = SteamUser.GetSteamID();
        string userId = steamID.ToString(); // Convert Steam ID to string
        string fileName = "pets_hungry_" + userId + ".dat";

        string data = hungry.ToString("F2");
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        int bytesLength = bytes.Length; // Get the length of the byte array

        bool success = SteamRemoteStorage.FileWrite(fileName, bytes, bytesLength);
        if (success) {
            Debug.Log("Saved hungry to cloud: " + hungry + " for user: " + userId);
        } else {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to save hungry to cloud.");
        }
    } else {
        Debug.LogError("Steam is not initialized.");
    }
}

Today, I attempted to save a different variable, and the following code fails to save to Steam Cloud:
public float test = 100;

public void SaveTestToSteam() {
    if (SteamManager.Initialized) {
        CSteamID steamID = SteamUser.GetSteamID();
        string userId = steamID.ToString(); // Convert Steam ID to string
        string fileName = "pets_test_" + userId + ".dat";

        string data = test.ToString("F2");
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        int bytesLength = bytes.Length; // Get the length of the byte array

        bool success = SteamRemoteStorage.FileWrite(fileName, bytes, bytesLength);
        if (success) {
            Debug.Log("Saved test to cloud: " + test + " for user: " + userId);
        } else {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to save test to cloud.");
        }
    } else {
        Debug.LogError("Steam is not initialized.");
    }
}

The game engine I use is Unity. By the way, my steamworks tax review is still under review. Will this have any impact?
Even if you change a different name or add a different unity project, you still cannot successfully save it to the steam cloud, but the previously written method can work.
